# datatemplate in silverlight c#.net

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i am creating a datatemplate for items in listbox and loading it using 
`(DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(template)`, where template is

```
string template = String.Concat(@
"<DataTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'                                        xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>
<Border BorderBrush='#334873' BorderThickness='1,1,1,1' Width='450'>
<TextBox Height='72' HorizontalAlignment='Left' Margin='10,10,0,0'  TextChanged="OnTextChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" />"
...................
"</Border></DataTemplate>");
```

i m getting error because of "OnTextChanged" event registerd.

I want to register a event in the template code.

How to do it?

Comment: Please clarify what sort of even you are trying to connect and to what element?

Comment: it's in there - he wants to map the TextBox-TextChanged to a method OnTextChanged....

Answer (score 1):

To give you an answer: as you are using a Template it's rather difficult to map an event this way because the template doesn't *know* where it's put into. So `OnTextChanged` doesn't mean a thing in this context.

You should consider bindings instead. As you allready use a DataTemplate the usual story would be to Bindd the TextBox-Text property to some model-property

```
<TextBox Height='72' HorizontalAlignment='Left' Margin='10,10,0,0'  Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" />"
```

Of course the DataContext here should have a property `MyTextProperty` but without your code (where you use the template) I can give no further details.

Comment: no i deal with someother scenario where i need to register an event like that.

Comment: IMHO it's allways better to go the MVVM route and let the ViewModel handle this stuff